# ProcessingJS and PointerEvents

Tags: javascript, processing.js, pointer-events, leaky-abstraction

I’ve read the code of the last stable release of the processing.js library and, as I imagined, since the port is port of the "processing" programming language, there is no sign of support of pointer-events, which would be useful in web sketches.

After a long search I found a series of tutorials on the channel9 website (http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Sketchbooktutorial) called "Creative Coding with Processing.js for Windows 8 JavaScript applications".  They use a custom version of the library: it is called processing_rt and it supports the following events

```
pointerDown, pointerMove, pointerUp, pointerCancel, pointerOver, pointerOut
```

Is there another, less custom version of the processing.js library that implements these events? If not, would it be "production-safe" to use the processing_rt library?

[image: From the W3C Pointer Events Draft]

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood your question, but aren't those available in pure processingjs? http://processingjs.org/reference/ lists mouseMove, mousePressed, mouseReleased, mouseOver, and mouseOut, and I'm not sure what "pointerCancel" means.

Comment: The official version of processingjs only offers the mouse events. Pointer events are an abstraction that let you work with different pointer types (as [multi]touch, mouse and pen, even at the same time) through a single, coherent API.

Comment: I see, interesting. Thanks for the clarification. Sorry, but I don't know anything past that. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another, less custom version of the processing.js library that implements these events?

No.

> If not, would it be "production-safe" to use the processing_rt library?

No.